# Config file interpreter for Silverlight version of Windsor Container

Tags: castle-windsor

Silverlight version of Windsor container does not provide XmlInterpreter() for reading bindings from config file. Could someone suggest how can I implement my own interpreter?

The online document suggest reading a configuration file, creating an instance of IConfiguration and registering them into IConfigurationStore.

How and where can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available in Silverlight version of Windsor because Silverlight lacks `System.Xml` API that Windsor uses.

There's a [ticket for that in Castle's Issue tracker along with patch](http://support.castleproject.org/projects/IOC/issues/view/IOC-ISSUE-191) (I'm afraid outdated) for implementing this feature using LINQ to Xml.

This can give you some ideas. If you want to update it and make it pass all the tests, and perform well we can include it in the upcoming release of Windsor (2.5).

Comment: I downloaded the libraries, but there is now Silverlight version Castle.Windsor or is the implementation of XmlInterpreter is in some other namespace

Comment: Like I said - Silverlight has no System.XML API so Windsor for Silverlight does not have that in current version.